# How to find a path in cypher the ungreedy way

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Actually i'm modelling TEI-encoded XML-Text in a graph (words as a chain of nodes) and i want to find shortestPaths and only the very shortest path in a graph.
[image]
My query looks like

```
MATCH (w0:XmlWord)-[:NEXT*..6]->(n:XmlTag {_name:'lb'})-[:NEXT*..6]->(w1:XmlWord)
RETURN id(w0), id(w1);
```

And I need only the shortest possible path but neo4j gives me all possibilities until to the 6th step. The result should be the nodes *Vorträge*, *über*, *des*, and *Freiherrn*

Neo4j gives me back all possible combinations until to the 6th step.

If someone needs access to a sample-database just let me know.

Comment: Very good question and I think we’ll have some interesting answers. However, please clarify the return values in the example. Should there be two results: (w1: Vortrage, w2: uber); (w1: des, w2: Freiherrn)?

Comment: Looks like there is a typo. The query should be returning the IDs of `w0` and `w1`, correct? Also, can you show all the results that are currently being returned?

Comment: You are right. I'm searching for the IDs two word nodes to do some further work with them. But it would be interessting to know the path.

Comment: So in detail i need two result types, the IDs of the two word nodes in one case and the complete path of nodes for comparision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tough when you're using multiple variable-length relationships in the same path. You can however order the results by path length and filter for the ones with the minimum length.

```
MATCH path = (:XmlWord)-[:NEXT*..6]->(:XmlTag {_name:'lb'})-[:NEXT*..6]->(:XmlWord)
WITH length(path) as length, collect(path) as paths 
ORDER BY length ASC
LIMIT 1
UNWIND paths as path
WITH head(nodes(path)) as first, last(nodes(path)) as last
RETURN id(first), id(last);
```

Comment: works for me ;-) Now i'm testing it with longer paths.