# neo4j cypher text as a graph refactoring

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a graph-db with text as a graph. In the system the pagebreaks are expressed with (pb)-nodes. Now i want to modell the pages with (page) nodes which point to the begin and the end of the page.

Example of text in a graph with w-nodes for the words (the n-property is incremental):

```
(pb {n:1})-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->
(w)-[:NEXT]->(pb {n:2})-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->
(w)-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->(pb {n:3})-[:NEXT]->(w)-[:NEXT]->
(w)-[:NEXT]->(pb {n:4})
```

The result should add these nodes an edges:

```
(pb {n:1})-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(Page)<-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(pb {n:2})
(pb {n:2})-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(Page)<-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(pb {n:3})
(pb {n:3})-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(Page)<-[:FIRST_CHILD-OF]->(pb {n:4})
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are the `n` values for :pb nodes always ascending, and is it such that each ascending pair should be linked? (1 and 2; 2 and 3; 3 and 4 etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer i have found (using informations from here: [How to find a path in cypher the ungreedy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637780/how-to-find-a-path-in-cypher-the-ungreedy-way))

```
// Find pb tags
MATCH (t1:pb})
WITH collect(t1) AS tags

// create unique pairs
UNWIND tags AS x UNWIND tags AS y    
WITH x, y WHERE ID(x) < ID(y)
AND y.n = x.n+1

// create nodes and edges
CREATE (p:Page)
MERGE (y)<-[:FIRST_CHILD_OF]-(p)-[:LAST_CHILD_OF]->(x)
RETURN *;
```

Comment: You may want to double check the results here. This is giving you a near cartesian product of :pb nodes with each other (though the first pb node will always have a lower graph id than the second).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just added some additional informations to the question and the answer.